# How to keep theming of a view after changing type of view?

Tags: views, theming, distributions

I am using a Drupal distro(Recruiter).
The distro has a view of type "Rendered entity".
However I am interested to change the type of the view to "Fields".
However when I make the change,the default theming of the view dissapears.So I am interested to keep the default theming of the view.
How can I do that?What shall I inspect?I am not a theming/css guy so any help would be appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the Theme:Information link in the edit view page

https://www.drupal.org/node/352970

Comment: If you want to do this the lazy way, you can symlink the theming files for the new display to those of the old one.